# How to load data on the request of the user?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a website that shows the data from a database on the html table depending on the user input.

Here is some part of it:

```
<body>

    <h1 id="popup" align="center" style = "font-family: Verdana;">Архив Договоров Standard Life</h1>

    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for ID...">

    <table id="myTable" align="center" border="1px" style="width: 1400px; line-height: 30px;">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="18" style="font-family: Verdana;"><h2>Данные договоров</h2></th>
        </tr>
        <t class="element">
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">ID</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Продукт</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Пакет</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Основной договор</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Номер договора</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Страхователь</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Премия в валюте</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Комиссия в валюте</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Дата договора</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Дата начала договора</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Дата окончания договора</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Дата окончания страх. защиты</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Время расторажения</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Причина расторажения</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Статус договора</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Номер заявления</th>
            <th id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">Вложения</th>
        </t>

    <?php
        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td id="count" style="font-family: Verdana;"><?php echo $rows['idusr']; ?></td>
            <td id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;"><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
            <td id="title" style="font-family: Verdana;"><?php echo $rows['surname']; ?></td>
        </tr>

//Data is loaded here

    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </table>
<script>
        function search() {
        // Declare variables
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                if (td) {
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

The problem I have is that I want to load the data from the database depending on the ID number user inputs. The way the website works right now is that it gets all the data in the database resulting in the overload of the information. What I want to do now is to have an empty table at first and depending on what the user inputs in, load the data from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP API,
I think you can do the php code.

I recommend adding a button because every character entered can cause slowness in the future.

Use thead and tbody tag

```html
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody id="tbody">
</tbody>
```

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "domain.tld/reactiveData.php", // change to your php file
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {}, // this is data you send to your server, id="myInput"
    success: function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.length);

        let responseData = "";

        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            responseData += "<tr>";
            responseData +=
                '<td class="count" style="font-family: Verdana;">' +
                res["idusr"] +
                "</td>"; /** Not use id, class must be used. !!!! */
            responseData +=
                '<td class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">' +
                res["name"] +
                "</td>"; /** Not use id, class must be used. !!!! */
            responseData +=
                '<td class="title" style="font-family: Verdana;">' +
                res["surname"] +
                "</td>"; /** Not use id, class must be used. !!!! */
            responseData += "</tr>";
        }

        $("#tbody").html(responseData);
    },
});
```

Comment: What should I use for my php API? In my php file i just have a connection variable and a query variable that parses the information from the database.

Comment: You will have PHP and MYSQL Codes in the API. Let's say you sent id = "123" to the php file, you will bring the data from the database with the id = "123" in the related table, print it as JSON, and add it to your site with the javascript code I throw at you. You can search how to create PHP resting API.

Comment: thanks for the response! Does the ajax code you wrote send the input to the php file or should I write a new method that does that? Wouldn't type of the method be 'POST' if the input is being sent to the php file?

Comment: Yes, the "POST" method is the most accurate method since a data will be sent. I updated the relevant code to POST, thanks for the warning.